# how to make the image zoom(in/out) animation

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

I have a `div` container which have several images,like this:

```
<div style="width:600px;height:600px;>
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

And the image inside the `div` all have the same size.

Now when the `div` is mousescrolled,I want to replace the `src` of the images,during the replacment,I want to make the animation.(make the images zoom in / out).

In fact,you should have guess that what I want is much like the zoom animation of google map when you scroll on the maps.

Any suggestion?

======================================
update:

1)for single image,I know how to make the zoom animation either by js or css3.

However,the images inside the `div` are continuous in their content. Just like the `tile` in the goole map.

So I have to keep this continuous  during the animation,for example,when the image are both scaled by 1.1,then their position must be rechanged to keep the continuous  of their contents.

2) I have to support ie7+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works in all modern browsers except IE. Since, it is css3 solution.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css3_hover_image_gallery/

```
img {
-webkit-transform:scale(0.8); /*Webkit: Scale down image to 0.8x original size*/
-moz-transform:scale(0.8); /*Mozilla scale version*/
-o-transform:scale(0.8); /*Opera scale version*/
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Webkit: Animation duration*/
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Mozilla duration version*/
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Opera duration version*/
}

img:hover {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /*Webkit: Scale up image to 1.2x original size*/
-moz-transform:scale(1.1); /*Mozilla scale version*/
-o-transform:scale(1.1); /*Opera scale version*/
box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; /*CSS3 shadow: 30px blurred shadow all around image*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; /*Safari shadow version*/
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; /*Mozilla shadow version*/
}
```